# find property and change it in qml

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qml

I have there two files, the one is my main python-script, the code looks like this:

```
import PyQt5
import sys
import os

from PyQt5 import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtQml import *
from PyQt5.QtQuick import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    ctx = engine.rootContext()
    ctx.setContextProperty("main", engine)
    engine.load('qml/app.qml')
    win = engine.rootObjects()[0]

    # TODO: read language bundles

    # global variables for colors
    baseColor_color = '' # The baseColor
    openFilesListBackground_color = '' # The openFilesList background color
    textColor_color = '' # The base textColor

    _baseColor = open( '../.pybox-config/Colors/baseColor.color', "r" )
    _openFilesListBg = open( '../.pybox-config/Colors/openFilesListBackground.color', "r" )
    _textColor = open( '../.pybox-config/Colors/textColor.color', "r" )
    for line in _openFilesListBg:
        openFilesListBackground_color = line
    _openFilesListBg.close()
    for line in _baseColor:
        baseColor_color = line
    _baseColor.close()
    for line in _textColor:
        textColor_color = line
    _textColor.close()
    print("Base color is: " + baseColor_color)
    print("OpenFilesList background color is: " + openFilesListBackground_color)
    print("Text color is: " + textColor_color)


    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to change a property of an value in my qml file, the snippet looks like this:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    objectName: "window"
    id: window
    width: 830
    height: 600
    color: "white"
}
```

I want to change the 'color' property, but how can I do this? I found the other thread with the QDeclarativeView, but this doesn't works for me because I use the code above. I use PyQt5 with QtQuick 2.0.

~pixl2

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html lists the stock methods; one other way could be using Qt MetaObject mechanism to set the "color" property on the root QML scene object (your ApplicationWindow).